# Looping through JSONObject to Create Array Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, json

I have a `JSONObject` of the following format:

```
[{"ascii_name":"Rio de Janeiro"},{"ascii_name":"Riyadh"},{"ascii_name":"Rome"},{"ascii_name":"Rawalpindi"},{"ascii_name":"Rabat"},{"ascii_name":"Recife"},{"ascii_name":"Ra's Bayrut"},{"ascii_name":"Rajkot"}]
```

which has been created using the following code:

```
while($row = $all_cities->fetch_array())
{
 $myArray["ascii_name"] = $row["ascii_name"];
 $returnArray[] = $myArray;
}
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Now I am using a `Volley` task to load this into my Android app. In the `onResponse`method I want to obtain each of the city names and load it into an `ArrayList<String>` using  a `for` loop. This is my code now, however it won't work since `s` is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject a = jsonObject.getJSONObject(i);
                    ....... more code which isn't relevant 
                }
```

Comment: your server is returning `JSONArray` and not `JSONObject`, so no need to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
```

use

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
```

Also i think you are using StringRequest in Volley. Switch to JSONObjectRequest in Volley.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

}
```

But make sure you do you have correct JSON response. You can do that by printing your json using Log.d before you parse it.